# Overview path and php $_POST

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

In google maps response there is an array with a key called `overview_path` with an encoded value e.g. `ioffIbei@GzvFez@p_@uMjjBdhAvo@gBvdCp|@jgEpuBxpMyrCf}@oyDhjCcqAdb@}~`  <--way longer

With jQuery i have put this value into an input text field and submitted the form using method post.  I want to display the static map on the post page but a completely different map is showing.

```
    $polyline = $_POST['polyline'];
   echo "<img src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=enc:".$polyline."&sensor=false' />";
```

When i test the url in the browser the correct map shows but not on the POST page. i assume the encoding has been changed.  How do i solve this?

The complete polyline is `ioffIbei@`GzvFez@p_@uMjjBdhAvo@gBvdCp|@jgEpuBxpMyrCf}@oyDhjCcqAdb@}~@qPuaCzs@k~@{l@suClDqo@`c@cnA|`Ba`Bvc@oh@oTke@o}Bqz@q^wdDfHk{Auo@{NfOk_@vnA{yAt`BetBv_@y`C`cBy~@hmAgeAtr@_cAtw@sp@pYms@sm@kuBh]orAvd@k{CjM}aBzt@woBfnDsI~Xbo@qwAbxAmbClhBai@rkCaE~gAjRppAbvCh~@hnI`kArmD`g@|[hg@dCf~@|lAda@laAzfA~wE~`DttCxPf|Blc@rcBnbAfWxyAf~AhyB~mBrqA|w@pnA`iCfqCvtD~Y~_AvXeo@tfAxeBfzBjeFhxBhnHhxAoOffG|\dtChfCd{Bs]noBpjAv{KrzJnfAhzCrGzdHzq@lbB`sAwaB|yBoyC`tCq`BhiDomBjw@syA~eAoXd{@wPnaAurArqBe{@dfBe@pmCfE|pB_mHto@sgDzcBu`Fjr@etAxhAei@t`DswDnbC{vFryCk|BfvAeWpyBzu@faAlSp{@mb@ryBk{DhlCu|AveA|WfdAfv@hoAeo@roCmm@vyA|E~w@qy@ry@q}Cde@qvChh@e{A`aBgo@h}A~EndCsr@vmAwtAxb@guAj}Ai_BpaB{TdcEvKtvCqzBj}GyLlvHatBzlD}`H`gCkgDfxByhCbeAebDdbBstDrrCssCljA_m@`l@_qAh{@egDxa@y{CbhCaaDhbC}hCzcAcQjkAmq@biB_AbtIejBfwGizA|xEyNtuDud@pxApjAfsAzN`oCj^~uDvxDf}@~c@h|@e[lgBn\zi@b]x`@eEfxBaKjyEsR`{Am_BnmByv@`tAyZlh@k_DfyIghFvfAsi@v~AqItkBmMrz@vj@wb@||@ge@hMbT|eApa@xdAqa@ydAkU{dA~[gI~i@sdA|t@vq@v_EvfAxy@lc@noAog@ldCwpBlsB}g@~{@yAlwA~y@viAn]dcAfwAvnAlTpeBqTjjArVreBh`BllC{s@p{@_cAvt@}Bvm@sXf_AhWflCxlAbaEniB`tCzD`b@wfApcAaUj|A_lFenBsiIiCweChp@uhAlr@m{@zhBoi@hXeUeQeq@nAyuAz}@}wA|_B_fAwC}j@xWst@vyAoeBn~Ayi@`|Ak_AdhBkuB~eC{z@l]wiAlY`h@zUp_AhSpfA|w@g]jbAsQi{Bzo@qVxhBoj@jk@yOnLaTbDcZtt@cv@z}AoT|sBgbAdvCc_@~dCg`@r{C_j@hH`

Comment: `var_dump` the `$polyline` variable to see the values. Compare it and see whether and how the value is changed, once you figure out the pattern just encode it back? Perhaps, add it to your questions so someone will help you out.

Comment: by posting the data it will urlencode the data so you should decode using urldecode

Answer (score 0):

The encoded polyline contains characters which need to be urlencoded when you use them in a url(e.g. the `@` in your example).

```
   echo '<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?'
          .http_build_query(array(
            'size'=>'400x400',
            'path'=>'enc:'.$_POST['polyline'],
            'sensor'=>'false'
          ),'','&amp;').'" />';
```

Comment: i tried this and still the incorrect map is showing.  I'm scratching my head.  It's definitely something to do with post as i can display the map correctly on the form page.

Comment: please post the complete polyline

Comment: check edit to main post, i've added the complete polyline.  When i pass it through $_POST a different map is shown.

Comment: I just compared and there seems POST method seems to add a second backslash to parts of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it a second backslash is being added to the string.  I used stripslashes and the correct map is showing.

Comment: A better approach would be to URL-encoded the polyline. That will not only avoid the double blackslashes, but also ensure that HTTP requests with those polylines are valid and work well in all browsers.